# Optimizing Python loop with Numba for live load analysis

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numba

I have written some code that computes flexural moments imposed by different trucks for a bridge with 300 ft length. Truck data are contained in two lists: `ax_list` and `sp_list`, which are the axle weights and axle spacings, respectively.

There is nothing much to the code, however, this needs to be repeated for millions of different truck types, and I am trying to optimize my code, which takes real long time when the actual data size set is concerned.

I tried using Numba to see if I can get any speed gains, but it did not change the execution time, whether I add Numba `@jit` decorators for each function or not. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be welcome! I also included code to generate representative pseudo data for 1000 records below:

```
import random
from numba import jit
import numpy as np
from __future__ import division

#Generate Random Data Set

ax_list=[]
sp_list=[]

for i in xrange(1000):
    n = random.randint(3,10)
    ax = []
    sp = [0]
    for i in xrange(n):
        a = round(random.uniform(8,32),1)
        ax.append(a)
    for i in xrange(n-1):
        s = round(random.uniform(4,30), 1)
        sp.append(s)
    ax_list.append(ax)
    sp_list.append(sp)

#Input Parameters
L=300
step_size=4
cstep_size=4
moment_list=[]

@jit
#Simple moment function
def Moment(x):
    if x<L/2.0:
        return 0.5*x
    else:
        return 0.5*(L-x)

#Attempt to vectorize the Moment function, hoping for speed gains
vectMoment = np.vectorize(Moment,otypes=[np.float],cache=False)

@jit
#Truck movement function that uses the vectorized Moment function above
def SimpleSpanMoment(axles, spacings, step_size):
    travel = L + sum(spacings)
    spacings=list(spacings)
    maxmoment = 0
    axle_coords =(0-np.cumsum(spacings))
    while np.min(axle_coords) < L:
        axle_coords = axle_coords + step_size
        moment_inf = np.where((axle_coords >= 0) & (axle_coords <=L), vectMoment(axle_coords), 0)
        moment = sum(moment_inf * axles)
        if maxmoment < moment:
            maxmoment = moment
    return maxmoment
```

Then to run the loop for 1000 times:

```
%%timeit
for i in xrange(len(ax_list)):
    moment_list.append(np.around(SimpleSpanMoment(ax_list[i], sp_list[i], step_size),1))
```

yields:

```
1 loop, best of 3: 2 s per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a few quick points on your code:

- any future imports should be at the top of any code. Are you using this intentionally (2to3?) or this is leftover code?
- your loop to generate test data overrides `i` in two secondary loops - this is bad coding practice.
- you're using xrange, which is pretty much deprecated since Python 2.3. Are you really using Python 2.3 or you just have stuck with xrange?
- no entry point aka `if __name__ == "__main__":` to demonstrate the start of your code, you have pieces of code scattered around your listing.
- Your code as-is with the random function cannot prove Numba JIT nor caching will have any effect. My results for your functions show:

  CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=665297, maxsize=0, currsize=0)
  CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=1000, maxsize=0, currsize=0)

  Which is to be expected with a random dataset. It's recommended to put a real dataset somewhere on the 'net for people to use.
- SimpleSpanMoment uses a global variable `L`, you should rewrite the function to inject all variables (or create them inside the function) and not use global variables.
- cstep_size is unused.

Hope this helps you move towards a better implementation, to solve the performance issue. Good Luck!

Answer (score 4):

First off, you should not be using Python 2 anymore, if at all possible. It will be deprecated next year. The major differences (important for this code) are that `xrange` is now `range` and `print` is a function.

Next, since I am currently on mobile I do not have access to `numba`. But since you said it does not yield any performance gain anyways, I just removed it.

With these small changes, and wrapping your code in a function, your code takes about 20 seconds (on my mobile).

The first improvement is making `vectMoment` actually properly vectorized. As noted in the documentation, `numpy.vectorize` is hardly better than writing a `for` loop by yourself (though it does allow you to use broadcasting on the inputs).

```
def moment_vect(x, L):
    return np.where(x < L/2, 0.5*x, 0.5*(L-x))
```

Using this drops the execution time by about a quarter.

Now for the meaty part. Whenever you write a manual `while` or `for` while using `numpy`, you should ask yourself if there is no better way. `numpy` supplies you with ways to do operations simultaneously on whole arrays. Your `while` loop in your main function can be realized by building a 2D array of `axle_coords`. This takes into account that we know where the minimum element is (since `numpy.cumsum(spacings)` is increasing, it is always the last element). Then we `sum` along one of the axes and get the maximum of the sums. This uses the `numpy` functions.

With this we get:

```
def simple_span_moment(axles, spacings, L, step_size):
    axle_coords = -np.cumsum(spacings)
    steps = np.arange(0, L - axle_coords[-1], step_size)
    axle_coords = axle_coords[:, None] + steps[None, :]
    moments = moment_vect(axle_coords, L) * np.array(axles)[:, None]
    mask = (axle_coords >= 0) & (axle_coords <= L)
    max_moment = np.where(mask,  moments, 0).sum(axis=0).max()
    return max(0, max_moment)
```

And then, I would put the calling code into its own function:

```
def graipher(axles, spacings, L, step_size):
    return [np.around(simple_span_moment(ax, sp, L, step_size), 1) for ax, sp in zip(axles, spacings)]
```

Together, these changes reduce the runtime from about 20 seconds down to 0.5 seconds for me.

The outermost loop can not be as easily vectorized, since your data is a ragged array. It would also probably no longer fit in memory if you have millions of entries instead of a thousand.